# xUnit Unit Test Adding Model data to a List of Model

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit, nancy

I'm trying to unit test adding my `User` model to a `list` of `Users`. Below is my test:

```
[Fact]
    public void Add_User_To_User_List()
    {
        //Given
        var fakeGuid = new Guid("36a84feb-cd51-4f1f-9b19-6d8dc2c89d4a");

        _jsonService.DeserializeObject<User>(_fakeUserJsonFile).Returns(_fakeUserList);
        _guidService.NewGuid().Returns(fakeGuid);
        _jsonService.SerializeObject(_fakeUserJsonFile, _fakeUpdatedUserList).Returns(true);

        //When
        var result = _userService.AddUser(_fakeUser);

        //Then
        What Goes Here?????
    }
```

The method I'm testing:

```
public bool AddUser(User user)
    {
        var userList = GetUsers();

        user.ID = _guidService.NewGuid();

        userList.Add(user);

        var serializeObject = _jsonService.SerializeObject(_fileName, userList);

        return serializeObject;
    }
```

I just want to test that the `User` passed into the method is added to the `User List`. So obviously the only code I'm really testing is `userList.Add(user);` but I just don't know How to do it can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the result of your service is idd true as you expect it to be:

```
//Then
Assert.IsTrue(result);
```

Your next test would can be testing on a failure of the AddUser where the `_jsonService.SerializeObject(_fakeUserJsonFile, _fakeUpdatedUserList).Returns(false);` and `Assert.IsFalse(result);`

Comment: So I assert the method to be true even though I'm not testing that part of the test, I'm testing the `userList.Add(user);` part of the method?

Comment: I've done this and when it gets to `var serializeObject = _jsonService.SerializeObject(_fileName, userList);`, `serializeObject` returns true, now I looked at the `_fileName` and `userList` parameters and it's the same as my mock data, but it's returning false? I already have a unit test for `_jsonService.SerializeObject(_fileName, userList);` which passes every time and my mock data is correct so I don't know why it's failing it? It's faling on the `_fakeUpdatedUserList` parameter but it's correct so I don't know why it's failing at this stage

Comment: Is your _jsonService injected into your User logic class? It seems you are calling the service instead of the mocked one.

Comment: no `_jsonService` is mocked out in the constructor, The only thing it could be is that I've written the `_fakeUpdatedUserList` wrong, but it's just not.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Assert.Contains(_fakeUser, _fakeUserList);
```

Since you control which list the faked json service returns as the list of users you can assert that it contains the right users at the end of the test.

Comment: This still failed, when I debug through it this line of code `var serializeObject = _jsonService.SerializeObject(_fileName, userList);` returns false. I think it's because even though it's the same data, it's a different reference to that data so in memory it's actually different how do I get around this?